# Hamcrest assertThat() error - objects are not the same

Tags: java, api, testing, hamcrest, assertthat

I have trouble with comparing two object.

```
var response = api.getRequest();
response.statusCode(200);

response.body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema....);

var bodyResponse = response.extract().as(ExampleResponse.class);
var bodyExpected = ExampleResponse.builder()...build().

assertThat("Response body is not the same with expected body",bodyResponse, equalTo(bodyExpected));
```

In test I'm getting error that response body and expected are not the same :/

I couldn't upload image with compared object but belive me, they are the same (I checked in debugger) :)

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Is the `equals` method overridden in `ExampleResponse `?
By default in java, 2 references are equals only if they are exactly the same instance.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain more detalistic :)

Comment: `new Object().equals(new Object())` is false, because the `equals` method is not overridden. If you haven't overridden this method, two instances cannot be tested for equality.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but I think I found another solution using is(equalTo())
      So now, code looks like that :  assertThat("Response body is not the same with expected body", bodyResponse, is(equalTo(bodyExpected)));
and it is working :)

Comment: @Marcin that's odd, given that `is` doesn't do anything, it exists [solely to make tests read nicer](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is(org.hamcrest.Matcher)).

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the equals Method to check for equality.
You need to implement this!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34411967/579448)