# Java Stream distinct() with other chained operations that modify stream elements generates duplicate result

Tags: java, java-stream

I was testing some things with Java `Stream` and `distinct()` and I came across a scenario where if I change a object of the `Stream` after executing `distinct()`, the final result of the execution contains duplicate items.

Does it make sense the object to go to the next operation before the `distinct()` is finalized? How to ensure uniqueness without iterating through the entire list?

OBS: The Lombok: `@Data` annotation adds `@EqualsAndHashCode` in the Dto class which will automatically generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods!

```java
package br.com.marcusvoltolim;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Dto {

    private Long id;

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dto dto0 = new Dto(0L);
        Dto dto1 = new Dto(1L);
        Dto dto2 = new Dto(1L);

        List<Dto> list = Arrays.asList(dto0, dto1, dto2);

        System.out.println("Original list: " + list);
        System.out.println("List with only distinct: " + list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));

        List<Dto> streamList = list.stream()
            .distinct()
            .map(dto -> {
                if (dto.getId() == 1L) {
                    dto.setId(3L);
                }
                return dto;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Java Stream  with map after distinct: " + streamList);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Original list: [Dto(id=0), Dto(id=1), Dto(id=1)]
List with only distinct: [Dto(id=0), Dto(id=1)]
Java Stream with map after distinct: [Dto(id=0), Dto(id=3), Dto(id=3)]
```

I expected the result: `[Dto(id=0), Dto(id=3)]`

Comment: You need to implement `.equals(...)` method in your class. - Does this answer your question? [Java (Equals Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411932/java-equals-method)

Comment: @blurfus Lombok Annotation: `@Data` make this.

Comment: All set operations are reliant on hashCode values never changing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807233/does-default-hashcode-change-on-object-mutation). If they do, expect sets not to work properly.

Comment: @DuncG, I understand, but if distinct() generates a new distinct Stream, how would a subsequent operation influence the result?

Comment: The map step changes the second entry in the set, such that the 3rd element is therefore now distinct to the first 2. Hence 3 entries. Without the map step, 3rd element is duplicate

Comment: Exactly, but the map is executed after the distinct() which in theory should generate a stream with unique elements, right? The JavaDoc: Returns a "new" stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Comment: No, you are seeing that distinct #n is before map #n, not that distinct #1 2 3 is evaluated before map #1 2 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251971/discussion-between-marcus-voltolim-and-duncg).

Comment: @DunG, Now, I understand: distinct() uses a HashSet with the hashCode of the objects to optimize the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your "expected" behaviour you can't change the values for the list element in the list.

You have:

```
if (dto.getId() == 1L) {
    dto.setId(3L); // <--- Changing the contents
}
```

So you are chaning the value and the "equals" of the nodes.

For it to work correctly, you have to really MAP and not MODIFY:

```
if (dto.getId() == 1L) {
    return new Dto(3L); // <--- Map to new object
} else {
    return new Dto(dto.getId()); // <--- Map to new object
}
```